# Unable to read from Realtime Database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to read from the database. I can authenticate and save. Just not able to read.

I have tried ContOnMainThread.
I have tried to fire the load function after sing in only.

I cant find anything specific to this situation.

Logcat(Messages i felt i should share)

```
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity Player UID: sEtDwM1AGIVKMxR1fsJjwuPfrm32
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity DatabaseSaveLoad:GetUID()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity DatabaseSaveLoad:Load()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.110 21378 25794 Warn Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.128 21378 25794 Info Unity Loading Complete 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.128 21378 25794 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.128 21378 25794 Info Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.136 21378 25794 Debug CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 147600208; UID 10844; state: ENABLED
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity Config Built
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity FirebaseManager:Start()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity Instance
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity FirebaseManager:Start()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity Activate
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity FirebaseManager:Start()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.142 21378 25794 Warn Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity Starting Auth with token client.
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidClient:Authenticate(Boolean, Action`1)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity FirebaseManager:Start()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.143 21378 25794 Info Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.144 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl release : mNativeObject = 508408118416 - Surface(name=com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity$_21378)/@0x9404277 / android.view.SurfaceControl.assignNativeObject:567 android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1115 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1777 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:8953 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.144 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject s[508408118416]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.144 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject e[508408118416]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl assignNativeObject: nativeObject = 0 Surface(name=null)/@0x15f1dab / android.view.SurfaceControl.readFromParcel:1115 android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout:1787 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:8953 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3312 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2575 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:9916 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1010 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks:809 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame:744 android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run:995 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity Player UID: sEtDwM1AGIVKMxR1fsJjwuPfrm32
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity DatabaseSaveLoad:GetUID()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity DatabaseSaveLoad:Start()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.145 21378 25794 Warn Unity 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl release : mNativeObject = 508408389280 - Surface(name=Surface(name=ac99350 InputMethod)/@0xdc80f6f - animation-leash)/@0x3ab2a49 / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.ImeInsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:154 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject s[508408389280]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject e[508408389280]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl release : mNativeObject = 508408141296 - Surface(name=Surface(name=ba0644c NavigationBar0)/@0xfef046e - animation-leash)/@0x4396f4e / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject s[508408141296]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject e[508408141296]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl release : mNativeObject = 508408136016 - Surface(name=Surface(name=3472d89 StatusBar)/@0xe6c8822 - animation-leash)/@0x7bba97c / android.view.-$$Lambda$Rl1VZmNJ0VZDLK0BAbaVGis0rrA.accept:2 android.view.InsetsSourceControl.release:170 android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.setControl:202 android.view.InsetsController.onControlsChanged:833 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject s[508408136016]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info SurfaceControl nativeRelease nativeObject e[508408136016]
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info ViewRootImpl@a3a4625[UnityPlayerActivity] Relayout returned: old=(0,74,1080,2400) new=(0,74,1080,2400) req=(1080,2326)0 dur=5 res=0x1 s={true 512702957648} ch=false fn=7
2021/07/28 18:57:49.146 21378 21378 Info ViewRootImpl@a3a4625[UnityPlayerActivity] updateBoundsLayer: shouldReparent = false t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@65d8a02 sc = Surface(name=Bounds for - com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@0)/@0x56c8f13 frame = 7
2021/07/28 18:57:49.149 21378 25794 Debug HelperFragment Creating fragment
2021/07/28 18:57:49.151 21378 21378 Debug HelperFragment onResume called
2021/07/28 18:57:49.151 21378 21378 Debug SignInRequest signIn
2021/07/28 18:57:49.151 21378 21378 Debug SignInRequest Building client for: 8fdac14 (a:true e:false i:false wc: 605567159672-fennfincvvsj4vp07u1ufd4imksmhs73.apps.googleusercontent.com f: false)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.151 21378 21378 Debug SignInRequest canReuseAccount: false
2021/07/28 18:57:49.151 21378 21378 Debug SignInRequest signInClient.silentSignIn
2021/07/28 18:57:49.257 21378 25970 Info UnityAds com.unity3d.services.core.configuration.InitializeThread$InitializeStateLoadCache.execute() (line:253) :: Unity Ads init: webapp loaded from local cache
2021/07/28 18:57:49.270 21378 21378 Info WebViewFactory Loading com.google.android.webview version 92.0.4515.115 (code 451511534)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.285 21378 21378 Info cr_WVCFactoryProvider Loaded version=92.0.4515.115 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
2021/07/28 18:57:49.293 21378 21378 Info cr_LibraryLoader Successfully loaded native library
2021/07/28 18:57:49.294 21378 21378 Info cr_CachingUmaRecorder Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
2021/07/28 18:57:49.295 21378 21378 Info TetheringManager registerTetheringEventCallback:com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat
2021/07/28 18:57:49.296 21378 21378 Debug ConnectivityManager ConnectivityManager() mContext=android.app.Application@2524c69 getOpPackageName()=com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat getBasePackageName()=com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat getPackageName()=com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat
2021/07/28 18:57:49.397 21378 26025 Warn cr_media Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 QUALCOMM build                   : 0e5772e1da, I227baa4eae
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Build Date                       : 02/16/21
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.08
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Local Branch                     : 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Remote Branch                    : 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Remote Branch                    : 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Reconstruct Branch               : 
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
2021/07/28 18:57:49.408 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2021/07/28 18:57:49.411 21378 26050 Info AdrenoGLES-0 PFP: 0x016dd091, ME: 0x00000000
2021/07/28 18:57:49.683 21378 26075 Info UnityAds com.unity3d.services.core.api.Sdk.logInfo() (line:82) :: mediation detection is:{"UnityEngine":true}
2021/07/28 18:57:49.694 21378 25986 Warn SyncTree Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2021/07/28 18:57:49.701 21378 26075 Info UnityAds com.unity3d.services.core.api.Sdk.logInfo() (line:82) :: Requesting configuration from https://publisher-config.unityads.unity3d.com/games/4175169/configuration?deviceMake=samsung&screenDensity=420&screenSize=268435810&idfi=62b8b3bf-ec0f-434b-836a-d6d308a9cd43&advertisingTrackingId=2d6b53db-7fc1-4e3e-93c4-1e8002722969&limitAdTracking=false&connectionType=wifi&screenHeight=2287&screenWidth=1080&bundleId=com.DefaultCompany.ProjectMeat&encrypted=true&rooted=false&platform=android&sdkVersion=3480&osVersion=11&deviceModel=SM-G988U&language=en_US&test=false&analyticsUserId=48e2e9927da877673a52c684999e0798&analyticsSessionId=3407644339022458612&first=false&framework=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&adapter=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 26093 Info System.out (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 26093 Info System.out (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Error: Firebase
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Firebase.Extensions.<ContinueWithOnMainThread>c__AnonStorey9:<>m__0()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity System.Func`1:Invoke()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Firebase.<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey1`1:<>m__0()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity System.Action:Invoke()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Firebase.ExceptionAggregator:Wrap(Action)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Firebase.Dispatcher:PollJobs()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity  
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021/07/28 18:57:49.703 21378 25794 Error Unity
```

This is my FirebaseManager/Authentication Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Database;

public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DatabaseSaveLoad databaseSaveLoad;
    private void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Play Games Configuration and Activate it. 
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
            .Build();
        Debug.LogWarning("Config Built");
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config); Debug.LogWarning("Instance");
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate(); Debug.LogWarning("Activate");

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance; // Sign In and Get a server auth code. 
        UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick: Failed to Sign into Play Games Services.");
                return;
            }
            string authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick: Signed into Play Games Services but failed to get the server auth code.");
                return;
            }
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: Auth code is: {0}", authCode); // Use Server Auth Code to make a credential 

            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode); // Sign In to Firebase with the credential
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogWarning("SignInOnClick: User signed in successfully");
            });
        });


    }
}
```

This is my "DatabaseSave/Load" Sctipt

```
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DatabaseSaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Script References")]
    public MasterManager MM;

    [Header("Save System")]
    public bool IsLoading;
    public WaitForSeconds AutoSaveInterval = new WaitForSeconds(10);

    [Header("User Information")]
    public string UID; 

    [Header("Firebase")]
    public DatabaseReference reference;

    // Start //
    void Start()
    {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        GetUID();
        StartCoroutine(StartLoad());
        AutoSave();
    }

    // Pause //
    public void OnApplicationPause(bool pause)
    {
        if (pause == true)
        {
            Save();
        }
        else
        {
            Load();
        }
    }

    // Coroutines //
    public void AutoSave()
    {
        StartTheCoroutine = TheCoroutine();
        StartCoroutine(StartTheCoroutine);
    }
    private IEnumerator StartTheCoroutine;
    public IEnumerator TheCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return AutoSaveInterval;
            Save();
        }
    }
    // Load
    public IEnumerator StartLoad()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Load();
    }
    // Save //
    public void Save()
    {
        if (!IsLoading)
        {
            //GetUID();// Check for players UID.
            PlayerSaveData saveData = new PlayerSaveData();
            Debug.LogWarning("Sending to Database");
            // Player Data Entered Below This Comment //
            // Money //
            saveData.MoneyOHAmount = MM.MoneyOH;


            // Player Data END //
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData); // Convert to JSON
            reference.Child("users").Child(UID).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json); // Send to Firebase Database as JSON

            Debug.LogWarning("Sent complete");
        }
    }

    // Load //
    public void Load()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        Debug.Log("Loading1");
        GetUID();

        PlayerSaveData saveData = new PlayerSaveData(); // New instance of PlayerSaveData.cs

        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users").OrderByChild(UID).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Error: Firebase");
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result; 
                string json = snapshot.Child(UID).GetRawJsonValue();
                saveData = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerSaveData>(json);

                // Load Data //



                // LOAD DATA BELOW THIS LINE //

                // Money //
                MM.MoneyOH = saveData.MoneyOHAmount;
                


                // LOAD DATA END //
            }
        });

        IsLoading = false;
        Debug.Log("Loading Complete");
    }

    // Get USER ID //
    public void GetUID()
    {
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;

        if (user != null)
        {
            string playerName = user.DisplayName;
            string uid = user.UserId;

            Debug.LogWarning("Player UID: " + uid);
            UID = uid;
        }
        else
        {
            UID = "No UID";
        }
    }
}
```

My Firebase rules are as follows

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Edit] Add Database Script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerSaveData 
{
    [Header("Money")]
    public double MoneyOHAmount;
    public double MoneyThisRunAmount;
    public double MoneyAllTimeAmount;
    public double MoneySpentThisRunAmount;
    public double MoneySpentAllTimeAmount;
    public double MoneyBeforeBoostsAmount;
    public double MoneyAfterBoostAmount;

    [Header("Premium")]
    public double CloudCoinsOHAmount;
    public double CloudCoinsThisRunAmount;
    public double CloudCoinsAllTimeAmount;

    [Header("Player Boosts")]
    // Consumables
    public bool X2For5MinutesActiveBool;
    public bool Discount25PerCentBool;
    public bool xBoost25PerCentXPBool;
    // Upgrades
    public float RacksPerDayCCUpgradeLVLAmount;

    [Header("Time")]
    public int SecondsAmount;
    public int MinutesAmount;
    public int HoursAmount;
    public int DaysAmount;
    public bool IsPMBool;
    public bool TimeSkipBool;

    [Header("Player: Stats")]
    public string PlayerUIDString;
    public float PlayerClothingLevelAmount;
    public float HatRankAmount;
    public float ShirtRankAmount;
    public float PantsRankAmount;
    public float ShoesRankAmount;
    public float HireChanceAmount;
    public float SleepAmountAmount;
    public float TimesUsedBenchTodayAmount;

    [Header("Currently Equipped")]
    public bool HasLameHatBool;
    public bool HasCoolHatBool;
    public bool HasRadHatBool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasLameShirtBool;
    public bool HasCoolShirtBool;
    public bool HasRadShirtBool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasLamePantsBool;
    public bool HasCoolPantsBool;
    public bool HasRadPantsBool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasLameShoesBool;
    public bool HasCoolShoesBool;
    public bool HasRadShoesBool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasHat1Bool;
    public bool HasHat2Bool;
    public bool HasHat3Bool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasShirt1Bool;
    public bool HasShirt2Bool;
    public bool HasShirt3Bool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasPants1Bool;
    public bool HasPants2Bool;
    public bool HasPants3Bool;
    [Space]
    public bool HasShoes1Bool;
    public bool HasShoes2Bool;
    public bool HasShoes3Bool;

    // PA //
    public bool NotAPrinterBool;

    [Header("Tutorials")]
    // Tut: Shop7
    public bool Shop7TutorialReadBool;
    public bool Shop7WorkTutorialReadBool;
    public bool Shop7InvestmentTutorialReadBool;
    // Tut: Thrift Store
    public bool ThriftStoreItemPanelReadBool;
    public bool ThriftStoreStatPanelReadBool;
    public bool ThriftStoreShopButtonReadBool;
    public bool ThriftStoreRackReadBool;
    // Tut: Hotel
    public bool HotelCostReadBool;
    // Tut: General
    public bool ClothingRankTutorialReadBool;

    [Header("Clothing Stats")]
    public double CurrentHatSpeedStatAmount;
    public double CurrentHatIncomeStatAmount;
    public double CurrentHatSaleStatAmount;
    //
    public double CurrentShirtSpeedStatAmount;
    public double CurrentShirtIncomeStatAmount;
    public double CurrentShirtSaleStatAmount;
    //
    public double CurrentPantsSpeedStatAmount;
    public double CurrentPantsIncomeStatAmount;
    public double CurrentPantsSaleStatAmount;
    //
    public double CurrentShoesSpeedStatAmount;
    public double CurrentShoesIncomeStatAmount;
    public double CurrentShoesSaleStatAmount;

    // Shops //

    [Header("Shop7")]
    public int CoffeeOHAmount;
    public int CoffeeInStockAmount;
    public int StarberryOHAmount;
    public int StarberryInStockAmount;
    public int OctoPopOHAmount;
    public int OctoPopInStockAmount;
    public bool Shop7OpenBool;

    [Header("Thrift Store")]
    public int RackStockAmount;
    public bool HasShoppedHatsTodayTSBool;
    public bool HasShoppedShirtsTodayTSBool;
    public bool HasShoppedPantsTodayTSBool;
    public bool HasShoppedShoesTodayTSBool;
    public bool ThriftStoreOpenBool;

    // Work //

    [Header("Shop7 Work")]
    public double Shop7WorkLevelAmount;
    public double Shop7WorkCurrentXPAmount;
    public bool HasAJobAtShop7Bool;
    public bool HasInterviewedTodayShop7Bool;

    [Header("Thrift Stoe Work")]
    public double ThriftStoreWorkLevelAmount;
    public double ThriftStoreWorkCurrentXPAmount;
    public bool HasAJobAtThriftStoreBool;
    public bool ThriftStoreCanWorkBool;
    public bool HasInterviewedTodayThriftStoreBool;

    // Investing //
    [Header("Shop7 Investing")]
    public double Shop7AmountInvestedAmount;
    public double Shop7InvestedLevelAmount;
    public double Shop7ROIPercentageAmount;
    public double Shop7CapitalGainsAmount;

    [Header("ThriftStore Investing")]
    public double ThriftStoreAmountInvestedAmount;
    public double ThriftStoreInvestedLevelAmount;
    public double ThriftStoreROIPercentageAmount;
    public double ThriftStoreCapitalGainsAmount;

    // Map Idle Business' //
    [Header("Map Idle Business'")]
    // M1P1
    public double M1P1InvestedAmount;
    public double M1P1MinCPHLvlAmount;
    public double M1P1MaxCPHLvlAmount;
    public double M1P1SellValueLvlAmount;
    public float M1P1CPHMinAmount;
    public float M1P1CPHMaxAmount;
    public bool M1P1CompleteBool;
    // M1P2
    public double M1P2InvestedAmount;
    public double M1P2MinCPHLvlAmount;
    public double M1P2MaxCPHLvlAmount;
    public double M1P2SellValueLvlAmount;
    public float M1P2CPHMinAmount;
    public float M1P2CPHMaxAmount;
    public bool M1P2CompleteBool;

    // Trash //
    [Header("Shop7 Trash")]
    public bool Shop7TrashAvailableBool;
    public int TimesLookedInShop7TrashAmount;
    public int TimeLookedInShop7TrashAmount;
}
```

I am able to authenticate and save on a google play build.

I have tried different variations of firing the load() void.

I hope i have supplied enough info for you to help me! I appreciate you taking your time.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your database structure? Are you maybe trying to access a value that doesn't exist?

Comment: And how can you log `Debug.LogWarning("Sent complete");` if you don't even know if that is true? You just know you started `SetRawJsonValueAsync` bit never check if it actually succeeded and if so you don't wait but immediately simply assume it worked.

Comment: I'm trying to learn all of this, hence why i cam here to ask some questions. I'm trying as hard as i can to learn this new step. I had no clue about this type of structure of code until i started doing firebase. I have been doing strictly unity since early last year. I put that log there to know that the function was firing. I watched my firebase to see if the data was being sent, which it is. I just cant read the data.

Comment: One workaround i have found is to set the firebase database rules to ```{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null"  
    }
  }
}
```

I would prefer it to be set to the user only being able to modify their own. Maybe this is not allowed with the way i have my system set up on the unity side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules should be like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid !== null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the firebase web console, you can use the playground to test your rules. Very helpful for setting up your database rules.

PS 1) You currently read the info for all users and on the client side get the data for the current user. This will not scale. Instead you could only read the data for the current user:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference($"users/{UID}").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(t => ...);
```

PS 2) As a side note when you get an exception it is a good idea to look at its message. Firebase usually has helpful exception messages. Firebase usually aggregates its exceptions, so something like below should do:

```
if (task.IsFaulted)
{
    Debug.LogError($"Firebase Error: {task.Exception.Flatten().InnerException.Message}");
}
```

Comment: ```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference($"users/{UID}").GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(t => ...);
```

You are awesome!!!